# I have to write every function i need for CouchDB?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, database, nosql

In MongoDB you have a lot of helper methods that do all the basic operations for you:

- count
- sort
- update
- replace
- etc...

In CouchDB you ahve to write map-reduce for everything by hand for basic operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some [built-in functions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions#Available_Build-In_Functions) for CouchDB and there's a [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) implementation for CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

#### It's all Map / Reduce functions.

Comment: But do I have to write everything by hand? Doesn't CouchDB provide wrappers or some other sort of help for basic operations like count, sort, find by key etc?

Comment: @ajsi: Not that I am aware of.